# Чем глобально отличается текстовый редактор от IDE?

Tags: веб-программирование, ide, sass, notepad++, интерпретатор

Не пойму в чем глобальное различие IDE и текстового редактора? Согласно википедии IDE включает в себя текстовый редактор, компилятор или интерпретатор, средства автоматизации сборки, отладчик.

Но насколько я понимаю, в интернет-технологиях IDE совсем не нужен, ведь автоматизация сборки - это что-то типа include, sass, Emmet (что также легко устанавливается и в качестве плагина для текстового редактора, Хотя как-то пробовал IDE-шку, там по-умолчанию не было ни sass, ни Emmet), отладчик - это табличка, которая появляется, когда ошибка в синтаксисе языка (по-моему по-умолчанию в текстовых редакторах встроен), интерпретатор думаю тут вообще лишний, т.к. самый лучший интерпретатор для интернет-технологий - это браузер? Или вообще все не так? Или может для интернет-технологий он лишний, но для обычных десктопных программ очень даже нужен?

Comment: В тред призываются свидетели vim'а.

Comment: Ну, к ошибкам в синтаксисе отладчик не имеет никакого отношения

Comment: @andreymal - а что тогда такое отладчик? Разве не тот, кто ошибки ищет?

Comment: @ПавелИгорев отладчик ищет ошибки, отслеживая процесс работы программы/скрипта, а работа возможна только при корректном синтаксисе. Во всех основных браузерах отладчик присутствует, а нужен ли он в текстовом редакторе/IDE для интернет-технологий, не знаю

Comment: @andreymal А я разве не то же самое написал (что ищет ошбки в синтаксисе кода)? Для какие технологий реально нужен IDE и в чем преимущество перед простым текстовым редактором?

Comment: @ПавелИгорев ошибки в синтаксисе не тоже самое, что в коде (например в логике работы).  И в IDE в принципе поддержка saas/less, Emmet есть. надо просто найти)...........`автоматизация сборки - это что-то типа include` - совсем **не** тоже самое

Comment: @ПавелИгорев `-3665e7.gdgdgdg(fgfh, gfh, fghfgh => f*ggfhgf-d4kleff, fdfgfg/0);` — здесь нет ни одной ошибки синтаксиса. Но, думаю, вы согласитесь, что этот код вряд ли выполнится? :)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский вы хотите сказать во всех IDE есть поддержка SASS по умолчанию? Дополнительно-то можно и к текстовому редактору прикрутить? А почему include нет? По-моему, грамотно проставленные include-ы могут реально ускорить разработку, а автоматизация сборки - это как раз действия направленные на ускорение разработки

Comment: Отладчик - средство проверки работы программы, например, написанной на php. Даёт возможность ставить точки останова, проверять значения переменных, осуществлять пошаговое выполнение и многое другое. Найти ошибку в серверной части сайта, выполняемой на php, без отладчика - крайне тяжёлая задача для любого среднего проекта.

Comment: @andreymal Как нет ошибки? Под синтаксисом понимаются допустимая комбинация символов для конкретного языка. Хотя для какого-то чудо языка может и нет.

Comment: @ПавелИгорев тогда укажите пожалуйста, что именно в моём примере недопустимо?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Так у браузер же не умеет думать. Он может только проверить заранее прописанный в него синтаксис (набор правил, опять же символьный набор правил)

Comment: @andreymal Смотря какой язык, смотря в каком контексте, может ее и нет

Comment: @ПавелИгорев я думал, в контексте интернет-технологий будет очевидно, что это javascript

Comment: @ПавелИгорев тем не менее вы сами сказали «может ее и нет», то есть текстовый редактор с подсветкой ошибок синтаксиса вам уже не помощник :)

Comment: @andreymal я не особо знаком с javascript-ом, поэтому не буду спорить

Comment: `грамотно проставленные include-ы могут реально ускорить разработку, а автоматизация сборки - это как раз действия направленные на ускорение разработки` - автоматизация сборки - это не какие-то банальные инклуды. Она включает множество этапов: например минификация, проверка на корректность кода, убрать лишний неиспользущийся код (бывает что-то упускаешь), преобразование языка в зависимости от настроек версии языка (например ES6 в ES5), в css например добавление префиксов к стилям, если в настройках указаны на какие браузеры рассчитан и многое другое

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский include в том числе и зависит от конкретной реализации, может они и лишними будут, это я для примера привел

Comment: @ПавелИгорев просто запустите WebStorm, поиграйтесь с ним денёк и вопрос отпадет.

Comment: На самом деле ответ содержится в вопросе: _**IDE включает в себя текстовый редактор**, компилятор или интерпретатор, средства автоматизации сборки, отладчик._

Answer (score 8):

В текстовых редакторах нет понятия "**проект**". Что даёт это понятие:

1. Радикальное ускорение поиска по коду, с помощью индексации текста проекта - это очень важно для больших проектов. На практике это секунда любого поиска по 100Мб текста .
2. Восприятие IDE проекта, как единого целого. В частности самая популярная фича - в коде написано что-то вроде `$obj->doSomething()` (PHP) <kbd>ctrl+click</kbd> на doSomething перебросит вас к телу этого метода `doSomething`, или к информации о функции, если она встроенная.
3. Возможность выбрать настройки для всего проекта, например кодировку.
4. Подсветка ошибок между несколькими файлами исходников, например вы создаёте метод в классе , аргументы которого отличаются по типу от аргументов класса-предка. В целом подсветка богаче - например скроллбар в PHPStorm может очень много сказать о большом файле с кодом: там отображены ошибки, варнинги, коментарии, TODO, фейлы навигации, git-изменения от HEAD; это очень помогает обозревать код.
5. Богатый автокомплит - начинаете набирать название метода/ф-ии/класса/css-класса, и тут вам точно подсказывают, как-будто за вас знают, что вы хотите сделать. Это очень удобно, и заодно немного обозревает структуру класса у которого вызывается метод.

В общем примеров ещё много можно привести - у всех них ноги растут из того, что проект для IDE единое целое, и он его "видит". У текстовых редакторов нет понятия проект - это ключевое различие.

Но даже без этого в IDE есть много специфичных полезных фич, например окно "Structure" описывающее структуру класса, открытого в текущей вкладке, например плагин для работы с Git из коробки. Не говоря уже о том, что качественную подсветку синтаксиса делают только специфичные редакторы вроде `Notepad++`, которые хоть и удобнее использовать как блокнот - но уже граничат с IDE по функциональности.

Главная цель IDE - красивенько уместить в вашей голове проект, даже если он большой. Тогда как редактор, даже навороченный - это прежде всего утилита(помошник), подходящая для небольших изменений.

Я например в `Notepad++` делаю заметки, смотрю лог ошибок(нотпад сам подтягивает изменения в файле - удобно), открываю исходники, обособленные от моего основного проекта, а также копипащу в новые вкладки куски кода - как памятку. В IDE же веду основную работу по проекту.

Answer (score 2):

Как один из примеров - это понимание структуры ООП. Сейчас я изучаю PHP и пользуюсь netbeans. IDE автоматом подставляет разные значение и подтягивает различные методы из другим файлов, как пример методы из абстрактных классов. При имплементации появляется значок предупреждения о необходимости перегрузки методов.
Используя IDE удобно передвигатся по коду, особенно в этом помогут всплывающие подсказки, когда по одному клику перебросит на другой файл с тем же абстрактным классом. 
IDE понимает и анализирует код на ходу, что дает возможность исправить ошибки, не запуская браузер.
Конечно, на маленьких проектах в несколько сот строчек кода хватит возможностей текстового редактора. В других случаях IDE будет незаменима, особенно при написании ООП кода

Comment: Т.е. он предлагает подстановку когда-то введенных переменных, методов из связанных файлов? Это в качестве плагина тоже есть в текстовых редакторах. И всплывающие подсказки, и ошибки есть в текстовых редакторах